# How can I debug inscrutable "internal error" in Metal compute shader? (Arbitrary code changes trigger)

Tags: ios, metal

I have a Metal compute shader for iOS that has started generating:  `"Error Domain=AGXMetal Code=1 "Compiler encountered an internal error"` errors during newComputePipelineStateWithFunction().

The errors are consistent from run to run but seem to be triggered by almost arbitrary modifications to unrelated code.  What I mean is - in naturally trying to debug why my adding the most recent chunk of code was ostensibly causing this problem I found that removing seemingly arbitrary and unrelated lines of code or constructs would remove the error.

I'm wondering if I may have hit some size or complexity limit of the compiler.

My shader function is less than 200 lines of code structured as a few C functions total and doesn't allocate much memory, but it does have some loops and hands off some buffer pointers.  Up to a certain point it was all working perfectly and the more recently added code is just more of the same.

My questions are:

1) First - what exactly is the compiler for the compute pipeline doing here (that wasn't done when my default.metallib was generated) and is there any hope of gathering more debug info from it?

2) If this is some kind of size or complexity issue with the code does anyone have ideas on how I might restructure to mitigate this?  Does any of this make sense?

It's going to be tough to post example code for this but I will try to update with it if a solution doesn't appear first.

EDIT:

So what I've done is painstakingly reduced and simplified my code until I have a relatively compact example that illustrates the problem. This was not as straightforward as it sounds because so many seemingly minor changes cause the problem to disappear, and yet it always returns when complexity is added back.

Please keep in mind that this is not about what the code below *does* - the failure happens when setting up the compute pipeline long before it runs.  If you see something obviously wrong please let me know but other than that the code is only meant to be representative.

The shader below fails on an A9 processor (iPhone 6s or 6s plus) but runs on an A7 (iPad Air first gen).

```
void myFunc( device int *ibuff0, thread int *ibuff1)
{
    int counter = 0;
    float fbuff0[8];
    for( int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
        if ( ibuff0[0] == 42 ) {
            fbuff0[counter++] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    float val = fbuff0[0];
    if ( distance( float2(0.0f,0.0f), float2(val,val) ) < 42.0f) {
        ibuff1[0] = 0;
    }
}

kernel void myKernelFunc( device int *ibuff0 [[ buffer(0) ]] )
{
    int ibuff1[8];
    myFunc( ibuff0, ibuff1 );
}
```

What's interesting is how many ways you can fix the above.  To name a few:  1) inline myFunc (either manually or using the inline keyword).  2) Comment out either buffer assignment.  3) Substitute a local buffer for the device buffer.  4) Comment out the for-loop, leaving the body.  Also the distance function call is not magic here and you can substitute any non-inlineable function that uses 'val' there.

By the way, here is a completely bogus one-liner version that fails on both A9 and A7 processors:

```
kernel void myKernelFunc() {
    while ( true ) { }
}
```

Some more thoughts -

I'm assuming what I'm running into here is some bug or limitation involved in the metal compiler trying to map these conditional and loop structures to the dynamically uniform type of code that can run on the GPU.  But I don't know why I got as far as I did in my code before hitting this wall since the above does not seem more complicated than the kind of stuff I was doing successfully.

Now that I have a sample I may file a bug with Apple (as some suggested).  But I wanted to share here in case someone has an idea.

UPDATE:

The easiest way that I've found to work around this problem is to manually inline some of my functions.

Comment: I would consider burning one of your Technical Support Incidents and contacting Apple directly. Fixing an error of `Compiler encountered an internal error` sounds like something only Apple can assist with.

Comment: You should definitely file a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com, ideally including the shader source and a sample project that provokes the error.

Comment: would love to know the outcome of this, if you found the cause, or if recent updates to the Metal compiler fixed it

Comment: The gpu allocated buffers need to strt on 16 bit bounds. An array of uint8_t arr[N] would generate this compilation error while uint16_t arr[N] would not.